# How can I detect if a person takes fall damage?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a command block creation that when you take fall damage, it gives you an effect. 
I am not using any of the methods that detect for air -1 meter of the player ( [1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FHbxagJePI) , [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/209443/how-can-i-check-if-a-player-is-in-the-air-with-testfor) )  because people will end up getting the effect if they are sneaking over a block or start jumping.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create two scoreboard objectives like following:

```
/scoreboard objectives add fall stat.fallOneCm
```

And:

```
/scoreboard objectives add damage stat.damageTaken
```

Then on a fill clock run:

```
/effect @a[score_fall_min=1, score_damage_min=1] EFFECT_HERE
/scoreboard players reset @a fall
/scoreboard players reset @a damage
```

How this works is that it effects all players with a fall distance statistic score of the minimum 1 which also has a damage taken statistic score of the minimum 1. After that it resets the scores so that it can happen again.

Comment: @user3878893 No problem!

Comment: Won't it trigger if get hit while falling?

Comment: Yes, altough that would be trivial to fix in 1.13, by adding `nbt={OnGround:1}` to the selector.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `minecraft.custom:minecraft.(fallOneCm|damageTaken)` for the scoreboards, and the effect command needs to be changed to `/effect give @a[scores={fall=1..,damage=1..}] ...`